# Switching to RootViewController

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I've got 2 different xcode projects. one is the main app, it's got the full design ready etc. and switches some screens. Then I've got an location app which show you the nearby hospitals etc. What I wanted it to do is if I press a button in the main app it goes to the location app. So I combined the two projects in one. finally it worked but now when trying to link the location app to the button it works but it doesn't show me the full screen. It just shows me a table with hospital, doctor etc. but i want to see the full screen of the location app. And i thought it was the rootviewcontroller. Here is the code:

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "VacaturesViewController.h"
#import "Over.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "NewKeywordViewController.h"

@interface Home : UIViewController {

//UI Button instance variable
UIButton *tweetButton;



}

// Properties
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *tweetButton;




// Methods
-(IBAction)sendTweet:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)vacatures;
-(IBAction)zoeken;
-(IBAction)Over;
```

And the .m file:

```
#import "Home.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "Reachability.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "InfoViewController.h"
#import "Keyword.h"





@interface Home ()

@end

@implementation Home

@synthesize tweetButton;




-(IBAction)vacatures {

    VacaturesViewController *screen = [[VacaturesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil       bundle:nil];
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];


}

-(IBAction)zoeken {

RootViewController *screen = [[[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]   autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];

}

-(IBAction)Over {

Over *screen = [[Over alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];


}





-(IBAction)sendTweet:(id)sender
{
NSString *tweet = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Door de Thuiszorg applicatie heb ik   altijd de juiste zorg in de buurt! Downloaden dus!"]; // Creates the string that is used for the tweet.
{
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweeter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];    // Allocates and initialises the Tweet "view".
    [tweeter setInitialText:tweet]; // Sets the text of the tweet to be that of the   NSString *tweet
    [self presentModalViewController:tweeter animated:YES]; //Present the Tweet view to   the user.
}
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:  (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}



@end
```

I hope you can help me guys!

Comment: the method `-(IBAction)Over` and class name `Over` both are same please make them different

Comment: Hi Aalok, Thank you! I've changed it. But the problem has to do with the 'zoeken' bit. And when i push the button to go to the RootViewController is only shows me a table of the location app and it doesnt do anything after that :(

Comment: check out your xib which view is bind to the -view of file's Owner reference outlate

Comment: Hi Aalok, this is the screen from the xib how it looks like, what do you think? http://www.de3kwasten.nl/Screenshot_4.png

Comment: so you need to init some viewController first not just RootViewController but some uiview and then assign it. specifically put some view to the rootviewcontroller and assign it as view from control drag from file's first owner this will solve your problem may be

Comment: Have you got some sample code? I've added a UIViewController above everything and changed the code "UIViewController *screen = [[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]   autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];

But this is not working either now when i press the button it shows me a black screen...

Answer (score 2):

You can change your root view controller simply by doing this.

```
 Over *screen = [[Over alloc] initWithNibName:@"Over" bundle:nil];
[[AppDelegate application].window.rootViewController = over;
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
-(IBAction)Over {

Over *screen = [[Over alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];


}
```

to this

```
-(IBAction)OverView {

Over *screen = [[Over alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];


}
```

and connect the button action to "OverView" opposing to Over

Comment: Hi ShiShi, Thank you, I've done this. But this doesn't resolves my problem with the Rootviewcontroller?

Comment: Ok guys, here is some more info about my problem!
See Screenshot_1 http://www.de3kwasten.nl/Screenshot_1.png this is the main app and when I click on Zoeken de yellow/orange button it goes to the Rootviewcontroller which looks like this.http://www.de3kwasten.nl/Screenshot_2.png But it needs to look like this..http://www.de3kwasten.nl/Screenshot_3.png and it's made like this in interface builder? Please someone help me!

Comment: you are calling the UITableView and not a RootController

viewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourViewControllerXibName" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];

Comment: Hi ShiShi, I already did that - RootViewController *screen = [[[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]   autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];